# If - Then Proof Regarding the Equality of Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A \subseteq B$ iff $(A\cap C)\cup B = B$ for any set $C$.

I believe this to be true. I know I have to prove the iff both ways.

If $A \subseteq B$, then $(A\cap C)\cup B = B$ for any set $C$.

and

If $(A\cap C)\cup B = B$ for any set $C$, then $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: Just pick $C=A$

Comment: @AndréPorto That's not sufficient. $C$ needs to be an arbitrary set. Unless you're attempting to provide a counterexample (but I don't see how it is one).

Comment: @OP - What have you tried? Where are you stuck? We're not going to do the proof for you; on this site it is encouraged that you include your own attempts and understanding of the problem, and a specific statement as to where you're stuck.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I was proving the reciprocal. Assuming that $(A\cap C)\cup B= B$ is valid for any $C$, it is surely valid for $C=A$, then, $A\cup B = B$, which implies that $A\subset B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If $A \subseteq B$, then $(A\cap C)\cup B = B$ for any set $C$.**

Proof:

$A \subseteq B \implies A \cap C \subseteq B\cap C \subseteq B$

Taking $\cup B$ over both sides:

$(A \cap C) \cup B \subseteq B \cup B = B$

---

**If $(A\cap C)\cup B = B$ for any set $C$, then $A \subseteq B$.**

Proof:

$(A\cap C)\cup B = B \implies A\cap C \subseteq B$

As $C\setminus B\ge\emptyset$, $A \subseteq B$.